# How to use model from exports module?

Tags: mongoose, module.exports

I am using Node.js and Mongoose. I am new at this so I 'm stuck.
When I run node app.js, I get this error :

TypeError: comCode.find is not a function

Here is my code:

```
    //companycode.js
    
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");

    const companyCodeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    country:String,
    companyCode:String,
    currency:String
    })

    module.exports = mongoose.model("companycode", companyCodeSchema);

    //app.js

    const comCode = require(__dirname + "/exports/companycode.js");
    
    app.get("/gn-companycode", function(req,res) {
      comCode.find(function(err, codes) {
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(codes);
                }
            });
```

Can you help me solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your app.js you will need to import your model as followed:

```js
let comCode = require("./path/to/companycode.js")
```

Comment: Thanks! I already found out why its not working. I am calling a wrong folder.